# Regular expression (Regex) to allow only number or specific character with number at a time

Tags: javascript, java, regex, validation

I have a requirement to allow any digits with only one character (either w or d or W or D) at a time with no sequence.

For example: 2 or 2w or 222W or 2d or 222D

(not like 2wd, 55dw, 2w5d, 2w5w, 2D5D etc)

Could you please provide solution on this. Thanks.

Comment: By "with no sequence" do you mean no two ws or ds may be next to each other?

Comment: You tagged this with both `javascript` and `java`. These are very different languages. Also, people are more willing to help if they see your current attempts at solving the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
^\d+[wdWD]?$
```

Try it out:https://regex101.com/r/sYqjTi/1

If you don't want it to match just `2`, remove the `?`, it will make the last letter required.

This regex should work both on Java and JavaScript.

Comment: Its working. Thanks much for the quick response.